# Why won't MySQL add these columns up?

Tags: mysql

I have a reasonably complex query, that I've simplified down here to try and make it understandable.

In the example below, I am trying to obtain a `SUM` of sales for two different products. When I retrieve the `SUM`s individually, as per the first two columns, they calculate correctly.

**However, when adding the two `SUM` queries together (in the third column), if product Y has been sold but *NOT* product X, the value returns as completely blank.**

Any ideas why this might be?

```
SELECT

  (
    SELECT SUM(IFNULL(product_x_sales.price, 0))
    FROM sales AS product_x_sales
    GROUP BY product_x_sales.customer_id
  ) AS "Total Sales of Product X",

  SUM(IFNULL(product_y_sales.price, 0)) AS "Total Sales of Product Y",

  (
    SELECT SUM(IFNULL(product_x_sales.price, 0))
    FROM sales AS product_x_sales
    GROUP BY product_x_sales.customer_id
  ) + (
    SUM(IFNULL(product_y_sales.price, 0))
  ) AS "Total Sales of Products X and Y"

FROM customers

JOIN sales AS product_y_sales ON customers.id = product_y_sales.customer_id

GROUP BY agents.id
```

Comment: Can you show us sample input/output?  Does it make sense to include those subqueries given that they are not aggregates or included in the `GROUP BY` clause?  Whence is the alias `agents` in `GROUP BY agents.id`?  I'm not sure that simplifying your query was a good idea.

Comment: To me this looks like as if you wanted to create a pivot table with an overall total value on the right hand side. Are you sure that this cannot be more easily achieved in the client application?

Comment: This isn't right. The resultset of the query will be incorrect. Basically, your query has **THREE** different SELECT statements doing their own thing.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen My example wasn't the clearest, sorry. The actual query I'm working on is huge (~1500 lines long), and much more complex. I tried to simplify as best as I could to only demonstrate the problem I was having, so some detail might've got lost in the simplification, Nonetheless, Johan's answer solved it for me, and hopefully others in the future too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When X has no sales, the result of your select would be NULL.
Adding NULL to sales of Y will result in NULL.

```
SELECT SUM(IFNULL(product_x_sales.price, 0))   <-- = NULL
```

Change it to this instead

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(IFNULL(product_x_sales.price, 0)), 0)
```

Comment: Thanks, that explained it clearly and has solved my issue.